# Sockets, recieving Serialization Exception

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, serialization

First off, I have read many guides and posts on StackOverflow and elsewhere and have still not solved this. I have been trying to learn about sockets recently and it is proving to be a challenge. I have understood how to use sockets with strings etc etc but I know want to start sending objects so I can better organise my program. I am making a chat client; the server will connect multiple clients, it will work a little like IRC I guess. I have made the very basics of the server; I have methods to check what packet type was received (all packets inherit from `Packet`) and have a very basic switch statement that takes action based on the packet received. Before this can be done I obviously need to convert the `byte[]` received in the socket to a `Packet`. The issue comes when I am attempting to de-serialize the byte array. I get a SerilizationException on the line where I call .Deserialize(); Here is the text:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was unhandled by
>   user code   HResult=-2146233076   Message=Unable to find assembly
>   'Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I don't get why this is happening; I have tried writing different ways of de-serializing the array, added random if statements to make sure I am not passing an empty array (which I am not) but can not get this to work for the life of me. I am hoping someone could point out what I an doing wrong? Am I going about sending objects via sockets all wrong? Have I simply missed something basic out from my code?

I have included the barebones of my client (all it does is send a `MessagePacket` with a string at the moment and my server is also included. Now, this program is not the prettiest by any means so I apologize in advance; this is all a learning curve for me!

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Chat_Application.Packets;

namespace Chat_Application
{
    class Server
    {
        private const int port = 1090;
        private readonly ManualResetEvent allDone;
        private readonly Dictionary<String, Socket> connections; // will hold all client sockets
        private readonly IPAddress ipAddress;
        private readonly IPEndPoint ipEndPoint;
        private readonly Thread listenThread; // seperate thread to run the server 
        private readonly Socket serverSocket;

        public Server()
        {
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            connections = new Dictionary<string, Socket>();
            ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(GetLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet));
            ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
            listenThread = new Thread(StartListen);
            allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        //called to start the new thread 
        public void Start()
        {
            listenThread.Start();
        }

        //TODO: implement this method
        public void Stop()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //method that is run on the new server thread
        public void StartListen()
        {
            serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            serverSocket.Listen(20);
            String statusUpdate = "\n<INFO> Socket bound, listening for connections...";
            Program.mainWin.AddConsoleText(statusUpdate);

            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptConnectionAsync, serverSocket);
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        //Asynchronus method to recieve connections. The logic of the way things are done is not great, it is only temporary while I learn better ways to do things
        public void AcceptConnectionAsync(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            var bufferBytes = new byte[1024];
            Packet packet = null;


            allDone.Set();

            var listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
            var client = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            client.Receive(bufferBytes);

            packet = ConvertPacket(bufferBytes);

            switch (CheckPacketType(packet))
            {
                case PacketType.Message:
                    packet = ConvertPacket(bufferBytes);
                    var messagePacket = (MessagePacket) packet;
                    String userMessage = "(" + messagePacket.userName + ") " +
                                            Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messagePacket.message);
                    Program.mainWin.AddConsoleText(userMessage);
                    break;

                case PacketType.Connection:
                    packet = ConvertPacket(bufferBytes);
                    var connectionPacket = (Connect) packet;
                    String connectionMessage = "\n<CONNECT>New connection established to " +
                                                connectionPacket.userName;
                    connections.Add(connectionPacket.userName, client);
                    Program.mainWin.AddConsoleText(connectionMessage);
                    break;

                case PacketType.Command:
                    // TODO Implement this case, add new packet type
                    packet = ConvertPacket(bufferBytes);
                    var commandPacket = (MessagePacket) packet;
                    break;

                case PacketType.Disconnect:
                    packet = ConvertPacket(bufferBytes);
                    var disconnectPacket = (Dissconnect) packet;
                    String disconnectMessage = "\n<DISCONNECT>User " + disconnectPacket.userName +
                                                " Disconnected succesffuly";
                    connections.Remove(disconnectPacket.userName);
                    if (disconnectPacket.goodDissconnect)
                    {
                        Program.mainWin.AddConsoleText(disconnectMessage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message = "\n<DISCONNECT>User " + disconnectPacket.userName +
                                            " Disconnected unexpectedly";
                        Program.mainWin.AddConsoleText(message);
                    }
                    break;

                case PacketType.Request:
                    // TODO Implement this case, add new packet type
                    packet = ConvertPacket(bufferBytes);
                    var requestPacket = (MessagePacket) packet;
                    break;

                case PacketType.Default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Packet Error", "Empty Packet Recieved");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        //used to check what type of packet has been recieved
        private PacketType CheckPacketType(Packet packet)
        {
            switch (packet.type)
            {
                case PacketType.Message:
                    return PacketType.Message;
                    break;

                case PacketType.Connection:
                    return PacketType.Connection;
                    break;

                case PacketType.Command:
                    return PacketType.Command;
                    break;

                case PacketType.Disconnect:
                    return PacketType.Disconnect;
                    break;

                case PacketType.Request:
                    return PacketType.Request;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;   
            }
            return PacketType.Default;
        }

        //converts the byte array to a packet
        private Packet ConvertPacket(byte[] bytes)
        {
            Packet packet = null;

            //try to convert byte array to a Packet, the error occurs on the last line; when trying to de-serialize
            /*try
            {*/
                var memStream = new MemoryStream();
                var binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
                memStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                packet = (Packet) binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
            //}
            /*catch (Exception) // MAKE THIS THE APPROPRIATE EXCEPTION
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An unexpected error has occured when atempting to convert a packet!");
            }*/

            if (packet != null)
            {
                return packet;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error converting packet!");
                return null;
            }
        }

        //gets the local ip
        public string GetLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType _type)
        {
            var output = "";
            foreach (var item in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (item.NetworkInterfaceType == _type && item.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    foreach (var ip in item.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            output = ip.Address.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Chat_Application.Packets;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class ClientWindow : Form
    {

        public ClientWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ClientWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessagePacket packet = new MessagePacket("Chris", "Hello Server!");
            byte[] data;
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(GetLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)), 1090));
            packet.type = PacketType.Message;
            data = ConvertPacket(packet);

            //to check if the packet has been converted correctly
            if (data != null)
            {
                socket.Send(data);
            }


        }

        public string GetLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType _type)
        {
            string output = "";
            foreach (NetworkInterface item in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (item.NetworkInterfaceType == _type && item.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in item.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            output = ip.Address.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return output;
        }


        private byte[] ConvertPacket(Packet packet)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                formatter.Serialize(ms, packet);
                bytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
            return bytes;
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception seems pretty clear to me. When you are trying to deserialize the data, the `Client` assembly that was referenced when the data was serialized is apparently not found.

Unfortunately, your code example does not include information about where and how you are declaring the `Packet` class. But based on your reported behavior, it seems likely to me that you have linked the same .cs file to two different projects, with the result that each assembly winds up with its own private copy of the `Packet` type.

If that's the case, then there are at least a couple of good solutions to the problem:

1. Define the type in just one assembly, and reference that assembly as needed. For example, you could define it in the `Client.dll` assembly, and then add the `Client.dll` assembly as a reference for the `Server.dll` assembly. Or you could build a third assembly containing the type, and have both your `Client.dll` and `Server.dll` assemblies reference that third assembly.
2. Use `XmlSerializer` instead. The XML won't include type information that requires a specific assembly to define the type in question. This is more commonly used when using `XmlSerializer` to map to and from XML that is processed outside of .NET (i.e. where sharing a common assembly to define a type isn't possible), but this approach could address your specific issue also.

Personally, I'd go with option #1, and put the type in a DLL shared by both client and server.

Comment: So you're saying I should create my Packet classes inh a new Windows Class Library from the VS menu, define the functionality etc there then export it as a .dll and refference the Packet classes from the imported .dll? I've never worked with .dll's but it should be easy from what I have seen. Just to make sure I understand, the error is occuring because I am refferencing two of the same object with the exact same name etc but from different projects?

Comment: @Sicarius:  "the error is occuring because I am refferencing two of the same object with the exact same name etc but from different projects?" -- yes, exactly. And yes, you should create a new DLL project as you describe. Adding it as a reference to the server and client projects is easy if they are in the same Solution, as the "Add References..." dialog has a "Solution" panel that lists projects in your solution. Just select the panel, check the new DLL as a reference, and you're good to go.